# How to parse triplets in a single line of input in C

Tags: c

I'm doing an assignment where I get input like this:

```
(x y z)
```

where `x`, `y` and `z` are integers, lets call it a triplet.

I need to get a lot of these, but in one line only. The input should be like this:

```
1 2 3 3 2 1 3 1 3 4 2 1 8 2 1
```

And I need to transform this input in triples, like `(1, 2, 3) (3, 2, 1), (3, 1, 3)` and so on.

My problem is, how do I read an entire (undefined size) line of numbers and store these?

Comment: Please post what you have tried, preferably a [mcve], and indicate where you are running into problems.

Comment: You could try something like sscanf() in a loop with a format string to specify three integers should be read. When the return value is not 3 then you know you no longer have read a triple.

Comment: Using `sscanf` would mean a line of unknown length has to be read first with `fgets`, and a triplet might span a broken line. You could more easily use a rigorously checked `scanf`.

Comment: if you are interested in actually learning how I strongly suggest you ignore any copy N paste answer you may be given and instead put your creativity hat on and think then ONLY lookup stepping stones to progress your own approach ... write code then experiment ... that approach is FAR better than merely receiving a solution from someone's labor and creativity

Comment: Is the line terminated with a newline (or CRLF if you're working on Windows)?  You say you need to store the triplets — what does that mean?  Store them for long enough to print them, or store them for subsequent processing after the printing?  What should be done if there is more information after the first line with all the triplets?  What should be done if there are 3N+1 or 3N+2 numbers?  What should be done if there's a letter in the input?  Are the elements of the triplets always single-digit numbers or can they be larger?  Negative?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with a simple `while(scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c)==3&&printf("(%d, %d, %d) ",a,b,c)>0);`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting input from standard input, you can use scanf to accomplish this, the following should be a good start, you should add more validation to complete the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x,y,z;

    while(scanf("%d %d %d ",&x,&y,&z)==3) {
        printf("[%d, %d, %d]\n",x,y,z);
    }
}
```

Using test.txt with the values you have provided, breaking them into multiple lines would work as well, as long as they are in sets of 3 and separate by space:

```
cat > test.txt << EOF
1 2 3 3 2 1 3 1 3 4 2 1 8 2 1
EOF
```

Running the example:

```
./a.out < test.txt
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 3]
[4, 2, 1]
[8, 2, 1]
```

Comment: The snag with that is that it will accept the input with one number per line, or indeed a random number of blank lines between each number.  Using `scanf()` where line input is wanted is pretty much an exercise in futility, at least where the size of the line is not sufficiently known in advance.